# How to set the default value for a custom property in declare-styleable

Tags: android-layout

I create a custom view to use in layouts and need to set a default value for its properties.

My view actually works almost perfect, but need default properties for better usability.

```
<declare-styleable name="ExpandableView">
   ...
   <attr name="expanded" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

How to make something like:

```
<attr name="expanded" format="boolean" default="true"/>
```

As I understand tag attr do not support "default".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in your implementation of `ExpandableView` as below;

```
val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.ExpandableView)

val expanded = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.ExpandableView_expanded, true)
```

I know it isn't quite what you're looking, but it should produce the same results.